# Inverse image of disjoint is disjoint?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inverse

If I have two sets that are disjoint i.e. $A\cap B=\emptyset$, and $\varphi \in C^1(U,\mathbb{R}^N)$, then are the inverse images (i.e. $\varphi^{-1}(A), \varphi^{-1}(B)$) also disjoint?

My logic supporting this assertion would be that from the definition of well defined: $$a=b \implies f(a)=f(b)$$

Therefore, taking the contrapositive, the disjointness seems to follow, but I'm not certain.

Does this seem reasonable?

Answer (score 4):

$$x\in \phi^{-1}(A)\cap\phi^{-1}(B)\Longrightarrow \phi(x)\in A\cap B...\text{contradiction...?}$$

Comment: It always holds. It's the definition of the inverse image: $$x\in\phi^{-1}(A)\Longleftrightarrow \phi(x)\in A$$

Answer (score 0):

If it were not disjoint, and they had the same set, then this would mean that this same set maps to two sets at the same time violating definition of function.

We have $A \cap B= \phi$ , consider $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$.

if $C=f^{-1} (A) \cap f^{-1}(B) \neq \phi$, then $f(C) \in A $ and $f(C) \in B$ contradicting the premise.